# Facebook all.js craps out when too many dom elements in IE8 - unresponsive script

Tags: facebook

I have facebook social modules/api on my page. I just started running into an issue and I can't locate any updates on all.js from FB that would cause this.

In IE8 if I include certain page modules (that have alot of DOM elements) the facebook all.js file craps out and IE bogs down and returns a "unresponsive script" popup.

If I reduce the number of DOM elements on the page, the page loads fine. I ran some page heuristics and such, and it points to all.js, but doesn't give specifics.

Anyone else run into this? Is there a setting that I can put on my DOM elements that tells FB to not recurse over it or ignore it.

It seems like FB all.js is crawling my page.

Any ideas or ways to really nail down the issue.

p.s. The issue was noted last Tuesday'ish... when they release their code.

How do I know it is all.js?

1. I hostFiled all third party scripts on my site one by one, to narrow down when my page throws the unresponsive error.
2. When I exlude facebook/all.js -- error goes away.
3. When I include FB all.js and omit some other modules on my page, I sometimes get errors, sometimes not - depends on the number (it seems) of dom elements on my page. FF loads great, IE8 nope.

Answer (score 1):

When th JS SDK is initialized with parameter `xfbml=true` it will go through the whole DOM to see if there are any Facebook HTML5/XFBML tags in it that need to be replaced with any of the social plugins – and since IE 8 is not the most modern browser, it does not offer very efficient ways to query for elements in the DOM (as getElementsByClassName etc.), so I think that might be the reason the script runs a very long time on a DOM with many elements.

So you could try to initialize the SDK with `xfbml` parameter explicitly set to false. If you *have* XFBML tags in your page that need parsing, you can use [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) to have it parse only specific elements or parts of the DOM, which will reduce the number of DOM nodes that need to be iterated over.

Please give that a try, and see if it helps to speed things up.